# Removing entire row if duplicate exists in one column

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet that contains around 60,000 rows. I want to delete all the data in the rows, if a single column (batch column) contains duplicates.

There is some variance in the data in the other columns, but I only want a single row for each batch.

I tried using the remove duplicates, but it would not remove everything, because of the variance in the other columns.

I wrote a macro, but it is painfully slow.

Does anyone know how to speed this up? Or maybe a better way altogether?

```
Sub Pull_Non_Variable()
    i = 0
    Do
        Current_Batch = Cells(i + 2, "J")

        'Cells(i + 2, "J").Select

        Next_Batch = Cells(i + 3, "J")

        'Cells(i + 3, "J").Select

        If Current_Batch = "" Then
            Exit Do
        End If

        If Current_Batch = Next_Batch Then
            Rows(i + 2).Delete
            'Range(Cells(i + 2, "A"), Cells(i + 2, "BI")).Delete
        Else
            i = i + 1
        End If

    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: When using Remove Duplicates you can choose the relevant column(s). With that amount of data, it would be worth putting it in an array and only writing back to the sheet once you've done the de-duping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by [SJR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7008044/sjr) in comments, you can choose which columns in the range dictate the duplicate criteria.

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A:BI").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=10, Header:=xlYes
```